# Detecting what Server Roles are installed on Windows Server 2012/2016

Tags: c++, windows-server-2012, servermanager

I am developing an MFC C++ application and I need to detect which server roles have been installed for Windows Server 2012 and later.

In Windows Server 2008 the Win32_ServerFeature class could be used. [Win32_ServerFeature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280268(VS.85).aspx)

For Server 2012 there is the ServerManager DeploymentProvider which has little documentation and I am not sure if it can be used with C++. [ServerManager Deployment Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872518(v=vs.85).aspx)

Is there any way in C++ to detect Server Roles on Windows Server 2012 and later without using Powershell Cmdlets?